# codeignitor 3 cached page not showing

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, browser-cache

I want display cached view in codeignitor 3. I am able to cache the view in folder but for some reason it never shows the cached page, instead is displays to current view file . code is below

```
 $this->load->driver('cache');
        $this->output->cache(20);
        $data['time'] = time();
        $this->load->view('cacheTesting',$data);
```

this code does create a cached view but for some weird reason it does not show the view it caches. i have tried everything and right now I am totally confused what is wrong here. pls pls pls help

Answer (score 1):

You have to save cache and then test if its valid, if not then create a new cache, like

```
$this->load->driver('cache');
$cache_id = 'time';
if (!$data['time'] = $this->cache->get($cache_id))
 {
   $data['time'] = time();
   $this->cache->save($cache_id, $data['time'], 60);
 }
$this->load->view('cacheTesting',$data);
```